# Calculate the time available in the service block in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Hi working on Production Model where I am working in shifts( 8:00AM to 4:30PM) and the requirement is that work should be done in one shift only otherwise shift it to next day. so for example lets say my agent enter the service block at 4:00 PM and shift end at 4:30 PM, the average  time require to complete this task is 3hours, What I want to do is to check the available time and if time is not sufficient ( like in this case i have only 30 mins) the agent should be sent to waiting area and next day service block should start working on that agent first.

Comment: Hi @Harsh, you really need to work to improve your questions. Happy to help but this is unintelligible... Again, please read https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and ideally also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Benjamin thank you for the suggestion I have updated the question, hope this might help.

Comment: Much better, thx :D

Comment: Also, always show what you already tried. It is easier for us and shows you already put some effort in yourself :) (Treat us like very busy colleagues that are happy to help)

Comment: and please also do not forget to upvote if answers are helpful, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way: Add A SelectOutput block ahead of the Service. In the condition, check

```
mySchedule.getTimeOfNextValue() - time() > x
```

Where x is the remaining time window you allow, i.e. the task duration the agent will require once entering the servive.

If there is not enough x left, you send the agent to some Wait block, else they are allowed to enter

PS: Also check the other functions that `Schedule` allows, might be you need some of them. Always check all capabilities a block offers you via code-complete (ctrl+space or Option+space on Mac)